# imagemapster IE9 not rendering hovers on hotspots

Tags: imagemapster

I've checked all the other ie9 related threads and can't seem to solve my issue.  In IE9 none of my hotspots are hovering.  It works in all other browsers.

I'm in IE9 Standards mode.
I'm rocking a doctype HTML5.
Nothing in the code jumps out at me.

Any suggestions?

LINK REMOVED

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code in `main.js` is throwing an exception in Internet Explorer. The mapster config never gets run when this fails.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

Site.init();

if (($.browser.msie) && ($.browser.version <= "9.0")) {

        $('input[placeholder], textarea[placeholder]').placeholder();
```

SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'placeholder'

Generally speaking, to troubleshoot in IE, just hit F12 and click "Start Debugging." It will be immediately apparent if a script is failing.

Comment: Headshake...  Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: No problem happens to the best of us!